# Long path Exception when in .net 4.8 class library but not in WIndows form app

Tags: c#, .net, path

Has anyone ever run into an issue with .net 4.8 (c#) throwing "too long path" errors like below when run from a class library project. The same line of code is working fine for me if I run it from a windows forms project.

the error is below
"The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters"

The code I'm using to get the error is pretty simple. StrPath is a valid path that is say 350 chars long. ("c:\<350 Char path and filename>")

```
string a = Path.GetDirectoryName(strPath);
```

That's the simplest example, but it also happens when using any File or FileIO method like File and FileStream where I reference the long path.

Things I've tried

- Most recommendations from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN
- setting the long path registry key
- Including app manifest with settings to recognize long paths. (there were two different types of these I found on the net, neither worked)
- prefixing with "\\?\"
- Looked at what mscorlibs are being referenced by both the windows forms and the exe calling the class library dll. Both were identical and referenced 4.8 libs.

Both projects succeed when I use a shorter path than 260. So it is really a path len issue I think. It just seems to behave as if I'm using an older version of .net when run from the class library.

I call the class library from within a native C++ app (its a com interop). I can also get it to happen if I make a class library with that code into an nunit text fixture and call it from nunit-x86.exe. So the code would be as below for that. And fails when calling GetDirectoryName

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Omtool.Properties;

using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using OmXceedInterop;

using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace XceedTest
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Class1
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            string strPath = "C:\\Kit\\BlahServer\\Work\\CompoundFile\\Xceed\\2a0bb008-397b-476a-8e89-96caa7a11319\\HLCUVL1221104974\\THIS_NAME_IS_TOO_FRACKING_LONG_TO_BE_IN_ANY_WAY_USEFUL_YOU_SHOULD_BE_A_FRACKING_SHAMED_OF_YOURSELF_HLCUVL1221104974_Container Inspection_NANDA TILES,SL-DOCUMENTO CONTENEDOR-NEXP-220199-STYLE ACCESS-FLOOR DECOR-BAYTOWN TX-NO.1001367035.pdf";
            int b = strPath.Length;
            string a = Path.GetDirectoryName(strPath);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Again, the exact same lines of code work from the forms app but fail when called from the class library. There is something different about these two projects or perhaps the context under which they run that I'm just not understanding.

[EDIT]
It has to be the context. When I run my nunit class from the forms app, there is no path error. When I run that same assembly from nunit-x86.exe, I get the pathing error. It seems to depend on what's calling the class library as to whether I get the error or not

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pathtoolongexception?view=net-7.0 this limitation was extended in .NET Framework 4.6.2. Could you please check if you use the same .NET Framework version in class library and winforms app?

Comment: I absolutely am using the same framework between them both. Both are targetting 4.8 and I see that the mscorlib loaded in both running programs is the 4.8 one

Comment: Seems like NUnit runner is loading a different framework version. Could you try reproducing this in debugger and then check which version is loaded?

Comment: Seems both the windows forms and nunit are loading C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll

Comment: Which version of NUnit are you using? I was not able to find `nunit-x86.exe`.

Comment: Yes an older version. 2.6.2.12296. Though nunit is only a quick way in which I repro the problem. The problem is the same when using the class lib via a native c++ app via com. Though I think you're probably right. Something is causing an older version of .net to be used. So far changing the specified dot net versions in app.configs for nunit and my lib haven't helped. I just need to find out what's causing the default to an older version in some cases and how to avoid that.

Comment: I reproduced it under this version of NUnit and attached the debugger to nunit-x86.exe process. It shows `C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll`. So it's really caused by the hosting application loading an older version of .NET Framework.

Comment: Interesting. Something to follow up on. It is definitely behaving like an older version.